# Core Data architectural issue NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8

I want to save the following son structure into Core Data.

// Json #1

```
{
1 = Viktor;
2 = Fries;
3 = "0179 2147911";
custom =     {
    name = Test;
    school = Harvard;
};
id = 0232;
status = 4;
lastupdate = 111111;
```

}

// JSON #2

```
{
1 = Viktor;
2 = Fries;
3 = "0179 2147911";
custom =     {
    age = Testage;
    color = blue;
};
id = 0232;
```

}

The User can customize the entries in custom by his own. Both JSON data should be saved using the same model.

I think I have to use a NSDictionary for the custom field.
What do you think?
How could I access the custom field in NSFetchedresultController?

// Model

```
class Contact: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var 1: String?
@NSManaged var 2: String?
@NSManaged var 3: String?
@NSManaged var id: String?
@NSManaged var status: String?
@NSManaged var lastupdate: String?
@NSManaged var id: NSDictionary?    <= Don't know how to implement it?!
}
```

How would should you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement `custom` as a separate entity, say `CustomValue` and give it two attributes, `name` (which could be "age", "colour", "name", "school", or whatever else the user chooses), and `value` (which will hold the corresponding value, "38", "blue", or whatever).  Then define a one to many relationship from your `Contact` entity to `CustomValue`.

One minor niggle is that `value` must always be of the same type (for which string is probably easiest) so you would need to convert that string to the correct type (eg. Int for "age").

If you name the relationship `customValues` then accessing the values is easy using key paths: `myContact.customValues.name` and `myContact.customValues.value`.